# EPS Figures in LaTeX Documents

Tags: floats, eps

I found some problems when inserting EPS images to my LaTeX document. There is no problem with the figure, the main problem is that on the left corner there is an "SS" that I have not written and I have no idea to delete them. Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Without any more detailed information in form of a *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) it is quite difficult to say something about the cause of the misbehaviour. Hence you should edit your question, add a small example and give a link to the place where you uploaded the concerned EPS file.

Comment: The `SS` appears on the image or around it on the document? If you open only the image using some image viewer is the `SS` there? You can use options to trim the image, for example, `\includegraphics[bb=a b c d, clip]{your-fig.eps}` where `a,b,c,d` are numbers. You have to read a little bit about *bounding box*.

Comment: Without more detail, this is 'unclear': the suggestion by Paul Melvin is quite possibly true but is really a guess as it stands!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you included an optional [height = xx pts] rather than [height = xx pt], for some number xx.  If you did, then an 'SS' would appear in the lower left corner of the figure.